# Variables assignment in templates

Tags: c++, templates, initialization

I am starting to use templates and I have what I imagine is a simple question but I was not able to solve it nor I was able to find a solution I can understand on the web.

I want a template which initializes a variable to some standard value, let say 0, (but It can be something different if needed).
Up to now I wrote this simple code:

```
template <typename T> 
void InitVar( T& Var){

    Var = T(0);

};
```

This code works for simple numberic types of variable, int, double, etc... But it is not working for different kind of variables such as strings.
I know that the problem is the T(0) command but I do not know how to substitute this with something more general.

In particular what I am interested in is a code which works on standard numeric variables and strings. Can someone help me?

Comment: It is suspicious that you pass an argument by value and initialize it inside a function body.

Comment: What does it mean to "initialize" something that already exists? Seems like that's the wrong way to go about something.

Comment: Sorry It was a typo in code I posted, I edit it

Comment: Why not: `template <typename T> make_initialized() { return T{}; }` Usage: `auto x = make_initialized<int>(); auto y = make_initialized<std::string>();`

Comment: @MeSS83 Still doesn't make sense

Comment: @KerrekSB Maybe initializing is now the correct word: what I want is to assign a default value to my variable, let say 0 for numeric type and the empty string "" or something else to strings

Comment: @MeSS83: OK, a bit silly, but if you must: `template <typename T> void ResetToDefault(T & x) { x = T{}; }`

Comment: If you need to worry about buggy compilers, consider `boost::value_initialized<T>()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, that's assignment, not initialization.

Anyway, you can use value initialization: `T()`
This will zero initialize arithmetic types or call default constructor of class types.

Comment: But this won't work if the type lacks a default constructor. I think he's missing the fact that the object is initialized before it is passed into the method. The only reasonable way to do this is a variadic template that takes all the parameters for the constructor. However, I don't see ANY reason to do this.

Comment: @Ben It sounds to me that DefaultConstructible is a requirement that OP is setting for T.

Comment: Depends... There's a difference between `T i;` and `T i = T();` if T is a scalar type.